# Sending a File Already in Memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-io

So I am pulling some data and processing it from a third-party API. After some re-formatting, I end up with a file in memory. I know that I can write that file to disk and then `send_file` or `render` it to the user for download by referencing the file name. However, is there a way to just render the file itself (since it's already loaded into memory)?

Every method I've seen has involved passing a filename, but this file only exists in memory and I'd rather not write to temp and then read back. I figured I need to render the right type of text and change the content_type, but I haven't found the right mix. Any advice?

Comment: `send_data` is what you need (the filename option is the "name of the download") [ActionController::Streaming](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html)

Comment: You should add that comment as an answer.

Comment: @sled, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks for the quick fix. Add the answer and I'll accept...

Comment: sending.. as in sending email..? .. as in streaming the file? pls be more precise..  If the data is in memory, it's good to go...

Comment: quote "to the user for download"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send_data` is what you need (the filename option is the "name of the download") [ActionController::Streaming](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html)